# How can we use Flex PMD for Flex Code Review

Tags: flex-pmd

How to use Flex PMD for Flex Code Review like the Eclips Jupiter Code Review?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for how you can run FlexPMD.  Since you haven't specified, I'll post the Ant script that I've used on Flex projects in the past.  It's just a snippet, so you might have to fill in some Ant variables, but it's a start.

```
<taskdef name="flexPmd"
    classname="com.adobe.ac.pmd.ant.FlexPmdAntTask"
    classpath="${flexpmd.lib.dir}/flex-pmd-ant-task-${flexpmd.version}.jar">

    <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${pmd.lib.dir}/pmd-4.2.5.jar"/>
        <pathelement location="${flexpmd.lib.dir}/*.jar"/>
    </classpath>
</taskdef>

<target name="flexPmdWithCustomRuleset">
    <flexPmd
        sourceDirectory="${src.dir}"
        outputDirectory="${flexpmd.report.dir}"
        ruleSet="${flexpmd.lib.dir}/pmd.xml"/>
</target>

<target name="flexPmdWithDefaultRuleset">
    <flexPmd
        sourceDirectory="${src.dir}"
        outputDirectory="${flexpmd.report.dir}"/>
</target>
```